# Redux Saga How to make component re-render after using update, add, delete request

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using Redux-saga to implement action such as adding user, editing user, deleting user. I want after each action, component will re-render by calling api to get new data (getEmployeeList function). Can u tell me how to do that? Thank u.

This is saga.js file

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import axios from 'axios'
import { 
    GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST,
    GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS,
    DELETE_EMPLOYEE,
    DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS,
    EDIT_EMPLOYEE,
    EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS
 } from './actions/EmployeeActions'
import ConstantList from '../../app/appConfig'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'


const API_PATH = ConstantList.API_ENPOINT + "/employees"

export function* getEmployeeList() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST, workEmployeeList)
}

export function* deleteEmployee() {
    yield takeEvery(DELETE_EMPLOYEE, workDeleteEmployee)
}

export function* editEmployee() {
    yield takeEvery(EDIT_EMPLOYEE, workEditEmployee)
}

export function* workEmployeeList() {
    try {
        const url = API_PATH + '/search'
        const response = yield call(axios.post, url, {})

        yield put({
            type: GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS,
            employeeList: response.data.data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Request failed!")
    }
    
}

export function* workDeleteEmployee({id}) {
    try {
        const url = API_PATH + '/' + id
        const response = yield call(axios.delete, url)

        toast.success("Delete Succeed!")
        
        yield put({
            type: DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS,
            id
        })
    } catch (error) {
        toast.warning("Delete Failed!")
    }

}

export function* workEditEmployee({ id, employee}) {
    try {
        const url = API_PATH + '/' + id
        const response = yield call(axios.put, url, employee)

        toast.success("Edit Succeed!")

        yield put({
            type: EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS,
            id,
            employee
        })
    } catch (error) {
        toast.warning("Edit Failed!")
    }
}
```

Thi sis EmployeeAction.js file

```
export const GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST = "GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST"
export const GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS = 'GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS'
export const DELETE_EMPLOYEE = 'DELETE_EMPLOYEE'
export const DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS = 'DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS'
export const EDIT_EMPLOYEE = 'EDIT_EMPLOYEE'
export const EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS = 'EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS'

export const getEmployeeList = () => ({
    type: GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST
})

export const deleteEmployee = id => ({
    type: DELETE_EMPLOYEE,
    id
})

export const editEmployee = (id, employee) => ({
    type: EDIT_EMPLOYEE,
    id,
    employee
})
```

This is EmployeeReducer.js

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify"

import { 
    DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS,
    EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS,
    GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS
} from "../actions/EmployeeActions"



const initialState = {}

const EmployeeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("action - reducer:", action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.employeeList
            }
        }
        case DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: state.data.filter(item => item.id !== action.id),
                openConfirmationDialog: false
            }

        }
        case EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS: {
            const data = state.data
            let dataUpdated = data.filter(item => item.id === action.id)
            const dataNotUpdated = data.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
            
            // console.log("newData:", filterData)
            // console.log("action-edit:", action)
            return {
                ...state,
                update: state.data.filter(item => item.id === action.id)
            }
        }
        default: 
            return { ...state }
    }
    
}

export default EmployeeReducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details will depend on you, but generally there are two approaches how to handle this.

1. Call the `workEmployeeList` saga from the other sagas.

```js
export function* workDeleteEmployee({id}) {
    try {
        const url = API_PATH + '/' + id
        const response = yield call(axios.delete, url)
        yield put({type: DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS, id})

        yield call(workEmployeeList) // here I call the list saga
    } catch (error) {}
}
```

2. Listen to the success actions

```js
export function* workSuccessWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery([DELETE_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS, EDIT_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS], workEmployeeList)
}
```

The difference between the two is the dependency direction. In the first solution the `workDeleteEmployee` depends on `workEmployeeList` while in the second one `workEmployeeList` depends on `workDeleteEmployee` (or in this case the new watcher to be more specific).

I personally prefer to use the first one when working within the same entity/module/file (like your case) and the second one when dealing with two different entities/modules/files (e.g. when we would want to update list of employee equipment when employees are created/updated/deleted).